# Casting InputStreamReader as (char)

Tags: java

I'm presently working my way through *Java: The Complete Reference 8th Edition* by Herbert Schildt. I'm a recent compsci grad and a novice programmer.

In the I/O chapter, the book presents a small piece of sample code (I've included it below). The code creates a BufferedReader that is supplied with InputStreamReader(System.in) as an argument (line 6). I checked the [Java SE7 docs for InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and it says that it "[...]reads bytes and decodes them into characters[...]". My question is, why is it necessary (or is it even necessary) to cast br.read() as a char when assigning it to 'c' in line 9 of the example code?

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Jamie

```
1.  import java.io.*
2.  
3.  class BRRead {
4.       public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
5.            char c;
6.            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
7.            System.out.println("Enter characters, 'q' to quit.");
8.            do {
9.                 c = (char) br.read();
10.                System.out.println(c);
11.           } while(c != 'q');
12.      }
13. }
```

Comment: did you read the javadoc for the `Reader.read()` method?

Comment: I did not (but I have now) and clearly I should have.

Answer (score 1):

`read()` method returns value of type `int`. Therefore, casting is required.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.read()` method is getting called from `BufferedReader` class and as per the documentation, your `br.read()` will return int. So in order to convert that int into char you need to cast it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

```
public int read()
         throws IOException
Reads a single character.
Overrides:
read in class Reader
Returns:
The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached
Throws:
IOException - If an I/O error occurs
```

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone for their input. I definitely see now that I should have read up on read(). Thanks for your patience with an newbie.

Answer (score 0):

The code is incorrect. 'c' should be declared as an 'int', so that comparing it to -1 is meaningful. The loop should exit if it is -1, otherwise it must be cast to a char when used as a char.